# How BufferedInputStream makes the read operation faster?

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I know wrapping BufferedInpurStream around FileInputStream makes read operation faster but trying
  to figure out how.I looked in to source code of BufferedInpurStream and got some stuff. Here is my
  understanding

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInpurStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
  int byteToRead;
  while((byteToRead = in.read()) != -1)
```

when i do bufferedInpurStream.read() , Internally ,it will first read the chunk of bytes at a time  in to buffer and then
  read each byte one by one from buffer instead of reading it from file(which is costlier).Once that buffer is empty
  it will fill it again with chunk of bytes

while with FileInputStream.read() , read operation is performed for each byte one by one from file which is very costly

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122422/usage-of-bufferedinputstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, read(byte[] b) (or read(byte[] b, int off, int len)) is prefered than read(), because it might have some IO performance advantages.

And if you use read(byte[] b), BufferedInpurStream have no acutal advantages, as long as you use same buffer sizes.

```
void read(InputStream inputStream, int bufferSize) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int read;
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
       // do some work
    }
}
```

and

```
void read2(InputStream inputStream, int bufferSize) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, bufferSize);
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read;
        while ((read = bis .read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            // do some work
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

try read and read2. you will find out that as long as you use appropriate buffer size, Wrapping to BufferedInputStream makes no performance improvements. (acutally it makes another computational costs...)

So, when do you need BufferedInputStream?
Here is my suggest :

- If you know "appropriate" buffer size, just handle it directly. It produces shorter code. 
  (ex: File reading. you can use file size as a buffer size.)
- If you don't know "appropriate" buffer size or you have to pass the InputStream to another library, wrap the stream as an BufferedInputStream.
  you may benefit from buffering. (ex: Web file transfer. server may not provide content-length field.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As you described, BufferedInputStream greatly reduces the number of IO calls made while reading one byte at a time from a stream (since most of those read() calls hit the buffer instead).