# What is the difference between FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream in Java?

Tags: java

What is the difference between FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream in Java?

Comment: Combine [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600331/why-is-using-bufferedinputstream-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte-faster-than-using-f) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122422/usage-of-bufferedinputstream) for answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [whats the difference in using InputStream instead of FileInputStream while creating an fileinputstream object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531824/whats-the-difference-in-using-inputstream-instead-of-fileinputstream-while-creat)

Answer (score 20):

Key differences:

- `BufferedInputStream` is buffered, but `FileInputStream` is not.
- A `BufferedInputStream` reads from another `InputStream`, but a `FileInputStream` reads from a file<sup>1</sup>.

In practice, this means that every call to `FileInputStream.read()` will perform a syscall (expensive) ... whereas most calls to `BufferedInputStream.read()` will return data from the buffer.  In short, if you are doing "small" reads, putting a `BufferedInputStream` into your stream stack will improve performance.

- For most purposes / use-cases, that is all that is relevant.
- There are a few other things (like mark / reset / skip) but these are rather specialist ...
- For more detailed information, read [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) ... and the source code.

---

<sup>1 - Or more precisely, from some object that 1) has a name in the operating system's "file system" namespace, and 2) that the operating system allows you to read as a sequence of bytes.  This *may* encompass devices, named pipes, and various other things that one might not consider as "files".  It is also worth noting that there some kinds of things that definitely *cannot* be read using a `FileInputStream`.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

**You must [google](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=H6j1UvmaKMHSrQeq6YGICQ) for that or read [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/),**

```
public class FileInputStream
extends InputStream
```

A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files are available depends on the host environment.

FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

For more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html.

```
public class BufferedInputStream
extends FilterInputStream
```

A BufferedInputStream adds functionality to another input stream-namely, the ability to buffer the input and to support the mark and reset methods. When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time. The mark operation remembers a point in the input stream and the reset operation causes all the bytes read since the most recent mark operation to be reread before new bytes are taken from the contained input stream.

For more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
1,2c1,2
< public class FileInputStream
< extends InputStream
---
> public class BufferedInputStream
> extends FilterInputStream
4,8c4,11
< A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files
< are available depends on the host environment.
<
< FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data.
< For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.
---
> A BufferedInputStream adds functionality to another input stream-namely, the
> ability to buffer the input and to support the mark and reset methods. When the
> BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes
> from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as
> necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time. The mark
> operation remembers a point in the input stream and the reset operation causes
> all the bytes read since the most recent mark operation to be reread before new
> bytes are taken from the contained input stream.
```

Comment: Erm. -1 for presentation, but +1 for chutzpah!